# Static class for constants with reference to java resources

Tags: java, android, singleton, constants, android-context

I want to store the colors I use in the colors.xml file. In addition to using them in an xml-layout, I also want to use these colors in my java-code, when drawing things to the Canvas.

The thing is, I am not always using the colors in a class that extends Application. For example, I have classes for objects that get drawn to the Canvas.

The thing is, I don't want to store the context in each class that needs access to my resources file.

My current solution is the following:

colors.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="colorOne">#123456</color>
</resources>
```

A static class called Attributes for constants, including colors:

```
public class Attributes {
    private static final Resources RESOURCES = MainActivity.getContext().getResources();

    public static final int ONE_COLOR = RESOURCES.getColor(R.color.colorOne);
    public static final int SOME_OTHER_CONSTANT = 1;
}
```

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private static Context context;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.context = getApplicationContext();

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    }

    public static Context getContext() {
        return context;
    }
}
```

And, finally in my object class:

```
public class ScreenArea {
    private Rect area;
    private Paint paint;

    public ScreenArea(Rect area) {
        this.area = area;
        paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Attributes.COLOR_ONE);
    }

    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawRect(area, paint);
    }
}
```

Okay, so first of all, this works. But, I am wondering if this is the right way to go. I have been reading about the Singleton class, but most examples are very basic an not focusing on storing constants, like I am doing right now.

So my questions:

- Is this the right way to go or should I implement a Singleton?
- If so, who can point me in the right direction?

Comment: Try on code review ... but no, it is not a right way ... just add field `private int color = Attributes.ONE_COLOR;` to activity and you will see

Comment: @Selvin: First of all, thanks pointing me towards codereview. I didn't realise there is a separate part of stackoverflow that focuses on reviewing code.

Comment: @Selvin: Of course, I could add all my constants to my activity. The thing is, though, there are quite a few and I want to keep my Activity class as tidy as possible. Hence the use of a separate classes for my constants (I also have static classes for, for example, database related constants and for networking)

Comment: .... also you can obviously have a problem when 1. start another Activity which also use ScreenArea ... 2. Second Activity goes backgroud(fx. Home button) 3. whole app gets killed (fx. some other app need memory) **4. user returns to your app from recent - so it will be Second Activity - obviously it will ends with NPE**

Comment: @Selvin: So, how to fix this. Through a Singleton?